# AngularJs Bootstrap typeahead detect event fired on enter key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angular bootstrap typeahead and the code is as given below.

Html :

```
<div class="col-sm-12 dlg-zero-margin-padding hide-last-result" align="left">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" 
        ng-model="selected" 
        ng-keyup="myKeyUp(event,this.value)"
        typeahead="item for item in filterInput($viewValue)"
        typeahead-on-select='onSelect($item)'>                       
</div>
```

My controller

```
$scope.myKeyUp(event, value) {
    debugger;
}
$scope.onSelect(event, value) {
    debugger;
}
```

When mouse focus is on any of the typeahead options, my onSelect function is invoked regardless of mouse click or enter key press. I.E it is called whenever a selection is made. But I want to differentiate between a mouse click and enter key selection as I want to add some different flow in each case.

How can I invoke 2 separate functions on enter key press and on mouse click. Or can I detect enter key press or a mouse click in my onSelect function?

Please note : On keyup event(i.e myKeyUp()) does not fire when I press "enter". Only onSelect function gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

inside your function you can identify if enter key is pressed and handle both case

```
$scope.onSelect(event, value) {
if(event.which ===13){
//enter is pressed
}else{
debugger;
}
}
```

Comment: typeahead-on-select does not allow you to pass the event. So this won't be possible

Comment: we can still differentiate using  ng-keypress="handleEnter($event)" here we can handle enter-key event, and on select we will handle mouseselect event